# Data stored in localstorage in browser show up on the screen

Tags: javascript, browser

We have a web application and we are using window.localstorage to store values in browser memory.

At times we see those values turn up at the down left side of the page. Most of the times, I have seen in Chrome browser. When we do Ctrl + f5, they vanish.

Did some face this problem? If yes how to solve this?

Comment: do you show those values on page in some case ? I doubt there'd be something fishy with your code. As nothing happens on its own :)

Comment: We dont show on the screen. It comes up as follows on the screen always at left bottom side.  {"Id" : 2984982, "code":sdfa899}

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the websocket calls that creating the issue. We are trying to send custom heartbeat from server. At times it is failing. And client assumes websocket connectivity is lost. So attempts to reconnect again, in this process at times data in localstorage content is corrupted and shown up on the screen. User has to refresh the browser to get rid of the problem for then. This happens randomly.